# Сортировка пузырьком на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

```
a = [1, 7, -3, 9, 0, -67, 34, 12, 45, 1000, 6,  8, -2, 99]
n = len(a)

for i in range(n - 1):
    for j in range(n - i - 1):
        if a[j] > a[j + 1]:                  
            a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]  

print('Отсортированный список:', a)
```

Вычитала в интернете про этот алгоритм, но не поняла как он работает(

Пожалуйста, объясните мне, как работает сортировка пузырьком (желательно подробно)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: неужто тут плохо описано: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC?

а что в нем описывать - вы бегаете по массиву O(n^2) раз и постоянно переставляете соседние элементы между собой если они находятся в неверном порядке и таким образом постепенно выставляете все элементы в порядке возрастания/убывания. Первый цикл проходит по массиву от начала до конца, а второй список от начала до того места где находится первый цикл - это позволяет сортировать все элементы

Comment: вот лучшее объяснение https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5JMInXAtnQg

Comment: Сейчас уже в каждом уроке кучу gif анимации того, как это работает. Простой наглядный пример такого: https://resultswebsitedesign.com/wp-content/themes/results-website-design/uploads/bubble-sort-animation2.gif

Comment: Вы правда думаете, что если вы в другом месте прочитали и не поняли, то мы вам как-то принципиально понятнее объясним?

Comment: Так мало что прочитали. Еще и код перед глазами. И в любой IDE его можно выполнить построчно. И вообчию увидеть, что происходит. Посмотреть в менеджере переменных как меняются значения массива. И так тоже непонятно? Но вы идете на форум -  и просите еще как то по особому вам объяснить. Может лучше - ну его, то программирование, если по всей имеющейся информации вы все равно понять ничего не можете.  Есть другие сферы деятельности, которые наверняка будут вам даваться проще.

Answer (score 0):

Все достаточно просто, в списке сравниваются стоящие рядом элементы, если порядок в паре неверный, выполняется перестановка элементов. Таким образом постепенно все элементы отсортируются.
Вот занимательное видео на эту тему: https://youtu.be/5JMInXAtnQg

Comment: Было бы здорово, если всё занимательное из видио [добавить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1288016/edit) прямо в вопрос. Принцип - лучше пара строк кода, чем длинные разъяснения со сслкой куда-то, на данном сайте к счастью сохранился.